# how to get Confidence score or probability score of Pix2struct VQA model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

How do we get the confidence score of the predictions for pix2struct model as mentioned below code in pred[0], how do we get the prediction scores?

```
FILENAME = "XXX.pdf"
PAGE_NO = 1
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

model = psg.from_pretrained("google/pix2struct-docvqa-base").to(DEVICE)
processor = psp.from_pretrained("google/pix2struct-docvqa-large")

def convert_pdf_to_image(filename, page_no):
return convert_from_path(filename)[page_no-1]

image = convert_pdf_to_image(FILENAME, PAGE_NO)

inputs = processor(images=[image for _ in range(len(questions))], text=questions, return_tensors="pt").to(DEVICE)

pred=model.generate(**inputs)
print(processor.decode(pred[0],skip_special_tokens=True))
```

i tried accessing the pred[0] to see if the confidence provided in the object but no refeerence how to check the probability score from the output